# How to print json array in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I create query in laravel 5.6

I need print json array in Jquery.

Return query in laravel is:

```
[
    {
        "day": 19,
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "day": 18,
        "count": 3
    }
]
```

Script code is:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
        "type": "serial",
        "theme": "light",
        "dataProvider": [
            {
                "day": 19,
                "count": 1
            },
            {
                "day": 18,
                "count": 3
            }
        ].reverse(),
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

I place `{{ json_encode($query) }}` in Jquery code:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",
    "dataProvider": [ {{ json_encode($query) }} ].reverse(),
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

But this code is not work...

How to issue this problem?

Comment: Given that the properties in the array you return are different to those expected in the actual code, I'm not sure why you'd expect this to work. You need to change the `day` and `count` property names. Also note that you don't need the extra `[]` around `{{ json_encode($query) }}`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Hi, my question is update. I can't remove `[]` becouse use `].reverse()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse json and remove an addition an array like below:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",
    "dataProvider": JSON.parse('{{ json_encode($query) }}').reverse(),
})
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: "dataProvider": JSON.parse('[{&quot;day&quot;:19,&quot;count&quot;:1},{&quot;day&quot;:18,&quot;count&quot;:3}]').reverse(),

Comment: You have two way to fix this problem:
1) JSON.parse('{!! json_encode($query) !!}').reverse()
2) JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($query); ?>').reverse()

Answer (score 0):

Replace `dataProvider` by the following code

```
"dataProvider": JSON.parse(<?=json_encode($query);?>).reverse()
```